# Dot doesn't match new lines?

Tags: php, regex

When I write a regex with `.` in it, it doesn't match new lines.

```
preg_match('/.*+?/') ...
```

What do I need to write, to match all possible characters, and new lines too?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add the [`s` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), e.g.

```
'/./s'
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `.` will not match newlines. You can change this behaviour with the `s` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` does not match new lines - and that is on purpose (though I am not really sure why). You would use the `s` modifier to change this behaviour, and make `.` match **all** characters, including the newline.

Example:

```
$text = "Foobar\n123"; // This is the text to match

preg_match('/^Foo.*\d+$/', $text); // This is not a match; the s flag isn't used
preg_match('/^Foo.*\d+$/s', $text); // This is a match, since the s flag is used
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the s modifier you should think about using a negated character class. Instead of

```
 #http://example\.org/.+/.+/.+#
```

you may use

```
 #http://example\.org/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+#
```

which ought to be faster.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   \r : carriage return
   \n : new line 
   \w : even [a-zA-Z0-9_] 
   *  : 0 or more. even :  +?
   $text = "a\nb\n123"; 
   preg_match("/[\w\r\n]*/i", $text, $match);
   print_r($match);
```

vide this list:

[image: http://i26.tinypic.com/24mxgt4.png]

Comment: That says `<` and `>` are metacharacters and have to be escaped with a backslash if you want to match them literally.  It also says `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries (start and end, respectively).  Can you say "Catch-22"?  Fortunately for us, neither of those things is actually true in PHP (`preg_*`) regexes. ;)